# Java How to remove Node in Meldable Heap

Tags: java, heap

How do I remove a specific node from a Meldable heap? I know how to delete the root and then meld the left and right nodes. I dont know how to find a specific node, delete it and mend the remaining nodes. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you have a link to the meldable heap code, or an article that describes the implementation you're working with? Without that, it's impossible for us to make suggestions.

Comment: http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/10_2_MeldableHeap_Randomize.html and https://www.javascan.com/684/java-program-to-implement-meldable-heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove a node in the middle of the heap, the first thing you do is update the parent node so that the parent no longer points to the node being removed. Essentially, you now have two heaps: the original heap, and the sub-heap rooted at the node to be removed.

Then, in the second heap (the one rooted at the node to be removed), you call `remove`. That removes the smallest item, which is the node you wanted to remove, and fixes up the heap.

Finally, you merge that second heap with the main heap.

The hard part is finding the node to remove. That requires a traversal of the tree structure, examining each node for the key.

If you want to avoid the sequential scan, you have to create a separate data structure such as a hash map that maps keys to heap nodes. Typically you'd have a wrapper data structure. Something like below, although forgive the syntax. Java isn't my strong suit:

```
class IndexableHeap
{
    MeldableHeap theHeap;
    HashMap<key, Node> index

    void add(node)
    {
        theHeap.add(node);
        index.add(node.x, node);
    }

    remove()
    {
        theHeap.remove(node);
        index.remove(node.x);
    }
}
```

I think you get the idea.